# Google Drive API Not showing all revisions

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

I have a Google Sheet that I use to track a project. It has a table on the first page with a bunch of project status stuff on it and I want to write a program to get that table for every revision and show how things have changed. The way to do that should be [this method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) of the Google Drive API. I did a simple `versions = self.drive.revisions().list(fileId=document_id).execute()` which at first seemed to work, but only has versions going back to 2023-03-25 while looking at the version history through docs.google.com shows versions going well into last year. I counted how many I see from that line of code and get 78 revisions. In fact, here's the full output.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revisionList",
  "revisions": [
    {
      "id": "43965",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-25T04:05:30.207Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "43995",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-25T19:41:57.778Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44001",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-25T20:46:32.836Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44003",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-25T23:35:26.866Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44016",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-26T01:13:46.495Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44022",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-26T03:53:14.166Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44046",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-26T05:00:20.680Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44053",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-26T18:24:55.648Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44059",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-26T20:41:01.992Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44060",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-27T05:05:01.388Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44090",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-27T08:47:04.164Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44104",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-27T15:33:17.366Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44112",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-27T19:18:54.392Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44116",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-27T20:27:10.369Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44119",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-27T22:04:14.144Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44131",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T00:36:44.902Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44161",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T05:28:48.960Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44180",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T15:22:06.105Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44196",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T17:17:20.094Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44198",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T18:41:19.696Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44200",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T19:48:34.181Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44202",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T20:33:35.024Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44211",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T21:53:54.675Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44220",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-28T23:55:24.729Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44248",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-29T05:02:39.648Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44291",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-29T15:31:04.617Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44298",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-29T18:33:24.005Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44317",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-30T17:59:07.158Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44357",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-30T19:36:08.531Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44363",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-30T20:31:52.080Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44369",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-31T03:10:20.864Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44400",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-31T06:44:00.598Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44407",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-31T17:07:06.371Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44432",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-03-31T19:23:29.108Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44457",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-01T10:02:35.601Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44459",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-01T12:50:52.237Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44469",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-01T15:57:27.930Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44477",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-01T16:41:27.471Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44487",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-01T18:00:38.356Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44494",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-01T22:20:56.778Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44520",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-01T23:57:37.239Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44533",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-02T01:05:43.422Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44555",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-02T02:31:42.116Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44602",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-02T04:06:10.102Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44613",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-02T14:20:36.278Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44617",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-02T14:52:09.802Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44661",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-02T16:37:41.966Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44671",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-02T18:04:39.310Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44677",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T03:02:32.600Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44707",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T04:12:13.984Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44754",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T05:29:27.675Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44760",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T06:42:45.964Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44781",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T16:03:11.685Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44785",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T18:09:33.417Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44789",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T18:51:08.286Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44793",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T20:31:42.634Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44797",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-03T21:33:15.528Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44809",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T01:41:33.395Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44816",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T03:17:24.988Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44854",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T03:59:19.549Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44873",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T06:08:36.895Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44890",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T08:34:15.162Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44934",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T17:41:27.133Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44948",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T18:31:12.263Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44979",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T19:41:40.078Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44981",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T20:38:27.040Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44987",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T21:22:10.843Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44989",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-04T22:35:15.787Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "44991",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T01:42:06.510Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45001",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T03:23:40.312Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45110",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T06:10:13.567Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45128",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T15:00:26.732Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45142",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T15:59:47.505Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45155",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T16:44:13.218Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45184",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T18:38:09.832Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45191",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T19:22:16.895Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45201",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T20:47:59.776Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "45205",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "modifiedTime": "2023-04-05T22:16:58.745Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

The API documentation says that if there are too many revisions it will respond with a `nextPageToken` that can be used to get the excess revisions, but that response doesn't contain one of those. Is there some other method I should be using or what?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need information about revisions in Google Sheets using Drive API.

Revision history stores a number of historical actions and edits made to a Sheet. This number varies depending on command complexity, amount of data involved in each command, and the frequency of edits made.

While revision history is large enough to cover most revisions in a file, **availability of all revision history is not guaranteed**. Changes made to the Sheet, like frequently reverting to an old version of itself, will reduce the number of available historical revisions. **Sheets that are very large and have frequent changes also tend to have short revision history.**

As referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/change-overview):

> Revision History
>
> > A record of all revisions of a file in chronological order. A change
> > to a Docs, Sheets, or Slides file gets a new revision. Each time the
> > content changes, Drive creates a new revision history entry for that
> > file. However, these editor file revisions may be merged together, so
> > the `API response might not show all changes to a file`.

Which in turn, explains this description from this [reference link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221FcFhnYWf0AEs1vZQWGPPmTKKtaBWS1ApBqpclkc-w4U%22%7D#response) regarding the `nextPageToken` property:

> **nextPageToken**
>
> The page token for the next page of revisions. **This will be absent if
> the end of the revisions list has been reached**. If the token is
> rejected for any reason, it should be discarded, and pagination should
> be restarted from the first page of results.

Comment: Sure, but when I click to see history from the spreadsheet itself I see all of the revisions that I want. How do I get the revisions that Sheets can see if the revisions().list() function doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I agree, that happens to me as well, but as per explanation from this [url](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/change-overview), the API response doesn't guarantee to fetch all changes to a file.

Comment: I wish the Google API guide had a browsable revision history, as references to unreliable revision results are no longer mentioned in the current version of the document! :) 
In my testing of Drive API v3 revisions.list with both the SDK and the Google API explorer, a maximum of 50 revision list entries are returned for a Google Sheet inquiry regardless of how small or large I set  the "pageSize" value. Searching the revision history through the Google Sheet web app shows all past revisions.